# How to make electron app process not close on user logoff (Windows)

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I need to make my Electron app to stay running in the background even when the user logs off from Windows.

Is there a way to run the Electron main process "globally"?

Just to context it: My app does readings from the serial port and saves into a sqlite database, so I need it to be always running, even when the user logs off.

Even a hint is appreciated. I couldn't find anything about it in my searches.

Comment: That sounds a bit odd for Electron to be doing. Could you have a standard persistent Node script do the readings and save, and then separately have an Electron app that interfaces with the script or database when the user wants to bring up a GUI?

Comment: Thanks for the response @CertainPerformance. That is an option, yes. I will look into that.